# Why do my tag helpers not work in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with 3 inputs using tag helpers and a data transfer object with these 3 properties.

When I add the object to my database the values are empty. I set the properties to [Required] and even this doesn't give me an error.

I declared this as model in the form cshtml file:
@model CRM_Collect.Dtos.ClientDto

Form:

```
<form asp-controller="Client" asp-action="AddClient" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="companyName">Company</label>
    <input asp-for="Company" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    <textarea asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="companyWebsite">Website</label>
    <input asp-for="Website" class="form-control" id="companyWebsite" placeholder="www.example.com">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Data transfer class

```
[Required]
    public String Company { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Website { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Comment { get; set; }
```

Post controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddClient(ClientDto client)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext();

        Client clientToAdd = new Client { Comment = client.Comment, Company = client.Company, Website = client.Website };

        clientContext.Clients.Add(clientToAdd);
        clientContext.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Is your client at AddClient null or it has values

Comment: and.. if it is not null, the ClientDto properties have values?

Comment: They are "NULL" and show up as "NULL" in my database. No errors.

Comment: You're not checking if the ModelState is Valid, you also don't have the spans on your page that will output an error message if they are invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I am using a version that doesn't support the helper tags. I am not using ASP.NET Core which is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly use the `FromBody` attribute on the action's parameter. Also consider check ing model state as the model is using `[Required]` validation attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddClient([FromBody]ClientDto client) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        using(var clientContext = new ClientContext()) {
            var clientToAdd = new Client { 
                Comment = client.Comment, 
                Company = client.Company, 
                Website = client.Website
            };
            clientContext.Clients.Add(clientToAdd);
            clientContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: [FromBody] can not be found and I can't find an import for it either. Is using FromBody the only way this can work?

Comment: @Niel You are probably missing a reference. Can you confirm the version of asp.net being used

Comment: according to the http headers: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common mistake I have seen when people try to post a form to a controller. You need to have the name attribute set on all your inputs of the form so the controller will process the data inside of the input field and correspond that to the properties of the model serving as the parameter of your action.

Your form should look like this:

```
   <form asp-controller="Client" asp-action="AddClient" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="companyName">Company</label>
        <input asp-for="Company" name="company" class="form-control" id="companyName" placeholder="Company name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <textarea asp-for="Comment" name="comment" class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="companyWebsite">Website</label>
        <input asp-for="Website" name="website" class="form-control" id="companyWebsite" placeholder="www.example.com">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: I thought it was related to my asp version I'm using for the project but I will try this out. Thank you